# How to assign a different audio URL for each reusable cell in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, audio, uicollectionview

I have 2 (or more) reusable collectionView cell and each one have to play a different audio. My problem is that when the audio1 finish, audio2 file start in the same cell of the audio2. If I manually play on each cell there's no problem, but if I want to play all audio automatically one after the other, all audio are played in the same cell.  How I can start the next audio in the next cell if the cell has not yet been created? 
Here how I append to array:

```
func appendToArray() {

    for (_, page) in self.resources.enumerate() {

        for (index,resource) in page.enumerate() {
            print("Passa di qui") // Qui passa

            if resource.fileType() == .Audio {
                S3Client.sharedInstance.downloadResource(resourceKey: resource.value, completion: { (success, file) in
                    // let files = String(file)
                    self.audioURLs.append(file)
                    /**
                     if self.audioURLs.count == self.resources.count {
                     // print("audioURLs \(self.audioURLs[index])")
                     MediaAudioPlayer.sharedInstance.queueTrack(self.audioURLs)

                     }
                     */
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    case .Audio:
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(MediaAudioCell.kCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MediaAudioCell

    cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    cell.activityIndicator.hidden = false

    S3Client.sharedInstance.downloadResource(resourceKey: resource.value, completion: { (success, file) in

        if success == true && file != nil {

            cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            cell.activityIndicator.hidden = true
            cell.audioURL = file!

            // Make slider indipendent from cell to another
            cell.sliderAudio.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.sliderAudio.addTarget(self, action: "sliderChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

            // print("ArrayURL: \(file)")
            // print("CiaoCell : \(self.audioURLs.count)")
            // print("Ciaoself.resources.countCell : \(self.resources.count)")

            /**
             if self.audioURLs.count == self.resources.count {
             // print("audioURLs \(self.audioURLs[index])")
             let item = self.audioURLs[indexPath.row] print("item: \(item)")
             }

             if self.audioURLs.count == self.resources.count {
             // print("audioURLs \(self.audioURLs[index])")
             // MediaAudioPlayer.sharedInstance.queueTrack(self.audioURLs)

             }
             */


            // Display total audio leinght
            let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: file!, options: nil)
            let audios = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)

            if let audios: AVAssetTrack = audios[0] {
                let audioDuration:CMTime = audios.timeRange.duration
                let seconds:Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration)
                cell.labelAudio.text = cell.stringFromTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(seconds)) as String
            }
        }
    })

    return cell
}
```

This is part of cell's Class:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Partenza automatica, dopo 2secondi, se Accessibilità su ON
    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        if self.defaults.boolForKey("AutomaticStart") == true && self.defaults.boolForKey("goBackPressed") == false {

            if let audioURL = self.audioURL {
                // Set AVAudioSession for recording and playing at the same time
                let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

                do {
                    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                    try session.setActive(true)
                } catch _ {}

                // If audio is playing, do not pass to next if cell is created, but    continue to playing.
                if MediaAudioPlayer.sharedInstance.player?.playing == true { // Se metto a    'false', ed elimino 'else', non parte in automatico.
                } else {
                    MediaVideoPlayer.sharedInstance.stop()
                    MediaAudioPlayer.sharedInstance.playPauseAudio(audioURL: audioURL, delegate: self)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the player class:

```
class MediaAudioPlayer: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    static let sharedInstance = MediaAudioPlayer()
    private var delegate: MediaAudioPlayerDelegate?

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    private var lastURL: NSURL?
    private var timer: NSTimer?

    internal var sliderTouched: Bool = false

    var tracks = Array<NSURL?>()
    var currentTrackIndex = 0

    override init() {
        super.init()

    }

    // MARK: Setup

    func playPauseAudio(audioURL url: NSURL, delegate: MediaAudioPlayerDelegate) {
        self.delegate?.playing = true // Set default play button on last delegate
        self.delegate = delegate // Save delegate

        self.sliderTouched = false

        // Setup as new only when this audio has not been already set up
        if (self.lastURL == nil) || (url != self.lastURL) {
            self.lastURL = url

            self.setupAudioSession(category: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

            do { // Setup Player
                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            } catch _ {}

            self.player?.delegate = self
            self.player?.prepareToPlay()

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(MediaAudioPlayer.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

        // Play - Pause
        if self.player?.playing == true {
            self.player?.pause()
            self.delegate?.playing = true
        } else {
            self.player?.play()
            self.delegate?.playing = false
        }
    }

    // Transform second to minute
    func stringFromTimeInterval(interval: NSTimeInterval) -> NSString {
        let ti = NSInteger(interval)
        let seconds = ti % 60
        let minutes = (ti / 60) % 60

        return NSString(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d", minutes, seconds)
    }

    // MARK: Audio Session

    private func setupAudioSession(category category: String) {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try session.setCategory(category)
            try session.setActive(true)
        } catch _ {}

    }

    // MARK: Stop

    func stop() {
        self.player?.stop()
        self.player = nil // Deinit player
        self.delegate?.playing = true
        self.delegate = nil // Deinit delegate
        self.timer?.invalidate(); self.timer = nil
        self.lastURL = nil
    }

    // MARK: Playing

    internal func playing() -> Bool {
        if player != nil {
            return player?.rate == 1.0 ? true : false
        }

        return false
    }

    // MARK: Seek

    func seekToPosition(position position: Float) {
        if let duration = self.player?.duration {
            player?.currentTime = Double(position) * duration

            self.delegate?.currentTimeAudio = stringFromTimeInterval((player?.currentTime)!) as String
        }
    }

    func update() {
        if sliderTouched == false {
            if let currentTime = self.player?.currentTime, duration = player?.duration {
                let time = Float(currentTime) / Float(duration)
                self.delegate?.sliderPosition = time

                self.delegate?.currentTimeAudio = stringFromTimeInterval((player?.currentTime)!) as String
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: Delegate
    var counter = 0

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        print("Called")
        self.lastURL = nil
        self.delegate?.playing = true

        /**
         if flag == true {
         nextSong(true)
         }*/

        /**
         if ((counter + 1) == tracks.count) {
         counter = 0
         self.delegate?.playing = false
         nextSong(false)
         } else {
         self.delegate?.playing = true
         nextSong(true)
         }
         */
    }
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: try use `NSOperationQueue` for your queue, easier to manage and you can initially put all playing to your queue but dont worry. It will play one by one when using `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1`

Comment: thanks for the answer...I know that I explained bad my problem, sorry. I try to explain better: my problem isn't play queue file, my problem is that I have an array with 2 item (..= [audio1, audio2] ), and I would like to play audio1 to the first cell and, when audio1 is finish, go to play audio2 in the next reusable cell. thanks in advance, and sorry for my English.

Comment: And second cell  is not visible because between the two cell I have some text.

Comment: maybe you can add some screenshots to your post to make it more clear. but i did the same thing, except that my cell will do download file automatically